The Magic Circle spell requires powdered silver and iron worth at least 100 gp to cast it; how much powder is that?
The component for casting Magic Circle is 100 gold pieces worth of Powdered Silver and Iron (or Holy Water, which we are not discussing here). 100 gold pieces is equivalent to 1000 silver pieces. At an average weight of one pound for 50 coins, that is 20 pounds of silver. Iron weighs less than silver (about 12% lighter) but is also worth much less, so adding more iron would probably only increase the weight.
How do you handle this in your game? Do you make your wizards carry 20 pounds of powder to cast Magic Circle one time? Is there an official interpretation of this component somewhere? What solutions have other DMs come up with?
The only idea I have come up with is that labor costs are high to powder any metal so that grinding a handful of silver costs 98 gold pieces - leaving about a half a pound of powder per casting.

"How do you handle this?" 16 strength goliath wizard, anyone?

"How do you handle this?"  Handle what? It's not really clear what your question is.

The "powdering process" is probably where the value comes from. Maybe the powder needs to be perfectly uniform and each grain exactly the same. A silver coin is impure, dirty, worn. Silver powder for a spell has a lot of work done on it... labour and special equipment costs money!
It might only really be 5gp worth of actual silver!

@Jack If one extrapolates from material prices, 100 gp of powdered silver and iron is 20-50 lb. Carrying five uses of Magic Circle would be difficult; was this intended? Should the weight be handwaved because of this? Now that I write that out, I see your point. Splitter has found something that doesn't seem fit, but it's hard to make a SE question out of that.

Related: What makes a spellcasting component worth x gp?

The left two speech bubbles in the first panel of this webcomic

Well, it says "silver and iron".  Since value per unit weight is a concern, better to have it almost all in silver, with just a light dusting of iron.

This is likely a case of oversight by the designers. If we assume a single flask of holy water is sufficient (it may not be due to the wording), then an equivalent volume (assuming that’s whats required here, since you’re making a magic circle out of it) of (pure) silver and iron in a 1:1 mix by volume is about 9.5 pounds and costs only 29 gp 5 sp. But 70 gp 5 sp in labor costs and markup seems excessive, even if we assume a significant amount of work to prepare the powder properly.

Have you ever read the Mistborn books? Magic in those books is powered by metal, which means there's an active trade in the specific alloys they need, with skilled metallurgists getting quite wealthy for providing just the right sorts of metal to highborn magic-users.
Why do you need such skilled metallurgists? Well, everyone can get normal copper or iron or such. But for magical purposes, the metal needs to be extremely pure, with extremely specific amounts of each element, and in the right form factor too. If you use impure metals, at best the magic won't work, and at worst you'll die.
I would rule the same for the components of magic circle. 100gp can buy you 20 pounds of silver, sure, but that'll be normal silver. Good enough for making coins and silverware out of, but nowhere near good enough for magic. 100gp only buys a small pouch of silver in the right formulation for a magic circle.
Mechanically, the weight of spell components is assumed to be generally negligible, even if those components cost money. Their value comes from the specific materials used, not the quantity of it—there's a reason there's no spell whose material component is "a cubic meter of granite", even though that might add some interesting resource-tracking to the game! So it follows that there's something special about the components of magic circle that makes them worth 100gp without weighing 20 pounds.

I have indeed read the Mistborn books and that is a very creative solution. I will run it by the group and see if that solves our quandary.

@Splitter Nice! I'm thinking specifically of the point in the first book where Vin runs out of pewter, and can't get any more—the skaa in the village have plenty of pewter things, but none of them are the right alloy.

To add in IRL context, pure silver is very rare in finished, worked form bc it's so soft it really can't hold a shape that gets used regularly--it bends and dents super easy. There's a reason sterling is .925; it's 92.5% silver and the rest alloy to let it hold up against regular wear/use. If you rule a purity threshold, silverware or silver coins are likely too alloyed to count.

@MissMisinformation Oh, that's good info! I didn't know that detail.

@Draconis I think you may be reading too much into MissMisinformation's correct comment. Regular silver is definitely too soft for silverware, but American Eagle Coins and some jewelry is made from 99.9% fine silver and holds its shape quite well under basic circulation and wearing. Silver is definitely soft by the standards of metal, but its not that soft and pure gold is noticeably softer.  But this is a great answer.

@TimothyAWiseman Yes.  Regardless of the actual purity of what is available as coins, the point is that making silver more pure than whatever standard is used to calculate its value will make that silver more expensive per amount of actual silver.  This refinement could be alchemical or magical or both.  The silver must be made to an arbitrary level of pureness to work in the spell, increasing its cost to whatever price point the DM wants in order to have the powder for the spell weigh whatever they want.

@Kirt Oh, I agree totally with your comment and with most of Draconis' answer which was excellent. I just think that Draconis was misreading MissMisinformation's comment when it got translated as part of the answer. Silver is soft compared to things like iron, but not that soft.

I think the problem might be that you are looking at this too literally or mathematically. It's good to remember that D&D is a fantasy world. There are some things that loosely match the ideas of weight and physics, but not necessarily. Also, the 100g coins' worth of powdered silver and iron may not weigh much. The cost of asking a smith (presumably) to grind silver and iron into a fine and pure powder will be included in the price. So the smith could charge 100g pieces for this product even thought it may not weigh all that much. It also does not specify ratio: silver is likely to be more expensive than iron in most campaign settings so the powder may only contain a small amount of iron.
In my campaigns I have allowed this to be a negligible weight which the wizard can carry in a component pouch (PHB, p.151).
I do not always use encumbrance (PHB, p.176) in my campaigns, mainly because it's a monumental bore. But, I have in the past, when I had players over-stepping the mark and wanting to carry two elephants' worth of belongings with them as they adventured. They learnt that that's what a trusted pony or donkey is for!
The alternative, which is much lighter potentially is holy water. 4lbs would cost 100g. (PHB, p.151) But, it may be much more pricey in your campaign if you want it to be. A few droplets could cost a 100g!

As mentioned in the answer by Draconis, purified and powdered silver can indeed be quite more valuable than the silver that is good enough for minting coins.
Moreover, not only do you have a problem with purifying silver, but you have the problem of it becoming impure.  Specifically, tarnish.  Silver will react with airborne sulfur and when you powder it you greatly increase the contact area, thus speeding the reaction.  Thus considerable care must be taken to keep your environment uncontaminated and then seal up the result into a packet for the caster.
And how are you powdering your silver?  When you apply destructive force to an object you generally get a bit of material transfer from the source of the force application to the target.  Note how any abrasive wears down over time--that's going into your product.  Most abrasives are used remove material and that doesn't matter, but in this case we are keeping it.  Somehow they need to purify it while retaining it's powdered nature.
(Personally, I figure a lot of this actually involves magic.  We only see the combat-focused part of magic, but it seems very unlikely that there aren't other spells.  Thus in cases like this you're not paying for a lot of labor, you're paying for some caster's time.)

It isn’t clear to me that this answers the question. While more facts about silver are interesting, this is not a discussion forum and answer posts must answer the question.

@ThomasMarkov I am expanding his answer by adding more factors that make high purity powdered silver more expensive than just the metal value.

I understand what you're striving for here, but I concur with Thomas. Even answers that expand on others should be able to stand on their own and right now, this one does not. As it currently is, this may be better if it's consolidated down as a comment on Draconis' answer.
